# Python SMTP email script stops working randomly

Tags: python, email, smtp

So I have a script that monitors my machine and creates log files and wanted to make another script that sends me an email with the content of the log file every time a new file is created. The problem with the said Script is that the email server randomly suddenly stops working and no longer sends emails. I cant reproduce a behaviour that trigger the problem and I am definitely not reaching the limit of emails sent. The code is below.

I have turned it into an exe file and it runs on autostart on Windows 10. It always runs when I turn the PC on and sends emails for a while and just randomly decided to stop. Any ideas whst the problem might be?

```
class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def sendmail(self, email, password, message):
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587)  
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail(email, email, message)
        server.close() 

    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created
        file_path = event.src_path
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_path), 'r') as input_file:
            content = input_file.read()
        self.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD, content)

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() # create event handler
# set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path="...")
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has announced that as of May 30th, 2022, it will disable control over Less Secure Apps on free Gmail accounts. (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

You need to use Google API insteed : https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/use-gmail-api-in-python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).